# Access underlying Model from a Renderer

Tags: python, django, svg, django-rest-framework

Currently, using just plain DRF I'm able to very easily render my models as JSON. This is straightforward (using `JSONRenderer`) since generating JSON from dicts generated by `Serializer`s is trivial.

Now I would like to be able to render my models as SVGs, but I'm rather stuck. I would need to inspect my models much deeper than what is available in the `data` parameter of `render()` on `BaseRenderer`s.

**All in all, I would need to retrieve the underlying model and access the ORM, from the `Renderer`**

I guess I could do that like:

- retrieve the `ViewSet` from the `context['view']` passed to `render()`.
- Retrieve the `Serializer` from the `ViewSet`.
- Deserialize the model's `data` thanks to the `Serializer`.
- Use the ORM to generate a proper SVG.

That seems very tortured for such a simple use case.

Is there an other way to be able to access the ORM and render SVGs for Models? Maybe I'm just not using the right tools, in the right order for the job?

Example:

Say I have two simple models: `Car` and `Wheel`.
`Wheel` contains a foreign key to its `Car`.
Now when I serialize `Car`, I would have the following:

```
{
    "url": "http://myserver/cars/1",
    "type": "limo",
    "wheels": ["http://myserver/wheels/1", "http://myserver/wheels/2", "http://myserver/wheels/3", "http://myserver/wheels/4"]
}
```

This is all great when dealing with JSON data, I expect the client to issue queries to the wheels if he wants to have more information on them.
But when I query the car to render SVG, I would need to draw it with its wheels! So I need from my SVGRenderer to access the ORM and retrieve information from the wheels: which color? which type ? etc

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the input and the expected output with models.

Comment: Instead of returning the urls in `wheels`, you can use a nested serializer like `wheels = WheelSerializer(many=True)`. This will return you all the attributes of a wheel which you can use to render.